# Is there a way to calculate the continuous probably of a part of a gaussian distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Say I have a gaussian distribution like $e^{-x^2}$.

How would I go about the probability of $a<x<b$?

The internet seems to imply that's not possible and the only way is a probability table, which makes this discrete?

Comment: The distribution is continuous, not discrete. A table of course has only a finite number of entries but you can interpolate any value between entries. Obviously it **is** possible to compute the values, that's how someone made a table; but it is very laborious and you would not want to do it yourself. There is software that can compute the probability more exactly than any probability table.

Comment: Best of luck in your future mathematical endeavors!

Comment: I'm wondering if by "not possible" you really mean "no nice closed form solution".  In other words, numerical methods are needed to approximate those probabilities.

Comment: I meant a simple closed form that I can write a quick program that does it for me for any arbitrary a,b.